# Hangman game with hard-coded word or phrase

Tags: c++, game, console, hangman

I feel that this implementation can still be simplified.  I've tried to keep variable scopes low and have used as much of the standard library as I could.

It currently works with a hard-coded word or phrase, but I eventually plan on having it work with random words or phrases from a file.

My main concern is in regards to my functions.  Am I using too few or too many of them?  I still feel that `main()` is doing a little too much.

Note: I have not tagged this as [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) because there's no utilization of it here, but I am open to any recommendations from C++11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool isCorrectGuess(const char guess, std::string const& word)
{
    return (word.find(guess) != std::string::npos);
}

std::string updateWrongGuesses(const char guess, std::string const& word, std::string wrongGuesses)
{
    return wrongGuesses += guess;
}

std::string updateCorrectGuesses(const char guess, std::string const& word, std::string correctGuesses)
{
    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i != word.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (word[i] == guess)
        {
            correctGuesses[i] = guess;
        }
    }

    return correctGuesses;
}

void displayStatus(const unsigned int triesLeft, std::string const& guessedWord, std::string const& wrongGuesses)
{
    std::cout << "\n\nRemaining Tries: " << triesLeft;
    std::cout << "\nWrong Guesses  : " << wrongGuesses;
    std::cout << "\n\n" << guessedWord << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    const std::string word = "rabbit rabbit";

    std::string guessedWord;

    // set up placeholders for word to be guessed
    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i != word.size(); ++i)
    {
        guessedWord += (isspace(word[i])) ? ' ' : '*';
    }

    unsigned int triesLeft = 8;
    std::string wrongGuesses;

    displayStatus(triesLeft, guessedWord, wrongGuesses);

    std::string attemptedGuesses;

    while (triesLeft > 0 && guessedWord != word)
    {
        std::cout << "\nGuess a letter: ";
        char guess;
        std::cin >> guess;
        guess = tolower(guess);
        attemptedGuesses += guess;

        if (isCorrectGuess(guess, word))
        {
            guessedWord = updateCorrectGuesses(guess, word, guessedWord);
        }
        else
        {
            wrongGuesses = updateWrongGuesses(guess, word, wrongGuesses);
            triesLeft--;
        }

        displayStatus(triesLeft, guessedWord, wrongGuesses);
    }

    if (guessedWord == word)
    {
        std::cout << "\n\nYou've guessed the word/phrase!\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\n\nYou've been hanged...\n\n";
        std::cout << "The word/phrase is: " << word;
    }
}
```

Comment: My personal preference is that main should try as hard as possible to do nothing but utilize other classes or functions. (preprocessor, selection, and loop constructs notwithstanding)

Comment: in my opinion it does not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing that nearly jumps out at me is this:

```
std::string updateWrongGuesses(const char guess, std::string const& word, std::string wrongGuesses)
{
    return wrongGuesses += guess;
}
```

It's not at all clear why you pass `word` to this at all, since it doesn't use or modify it. Worse, it looks like it's actually more work to call the function than to re-implement what (little) the function does. At least to me:

```
wrongGuesses += guess;
```

...seems simpler and more readable than:

```
 wrongGuesses = updateWrongGuesses(guess, word, wrongGuesses);
```

I think I probably would use a class (or possibly two) in writing this code. My first attempt would be something on this general order:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class hangman{
    static const int max_wrong = 8;
    std::string word;
    std::string display;
    std::string wrong;
public:
    hangman(std::string const &word) : word(word) {
        for (char ch : word)
            display += isspace(ch) ? ' ' : '*';
    }

    void enter_guess(char ch) {
        bool correct = false;

        for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i != word.size(); ++i)
            if (word[i] == ch) {
                display[i] = ch;
                correct = true;
            }   
        if (!correct)
            wrong += ch;
    }

    bool is_over() {
        return wrong.size() == max_wrong || display == word;
    }

    std::string final() {
        return "The word was: " + word + (display == word ? "\nYou win!" : "\nYou lose");
    }

    std::string status() {
        return "\nwrong guesses: " + wrong + "\nCurrent word: " + display;
    }
};

char get_guess() {
    std::cout << "Please enter your guess: ";
    char ch;
    std::cin >> ch;
    return ch;
}

int main()
{
    hangman game("rabbit rabbit");

    do {
        std::cout << game.status() << "\n";
        game.enter_guess(get_guess());
    } while (!game.is_over());
    std::cout << game.final();
}
```

As far as how much of your code is in `main`: I try not to treat `main` any differently from any other function. IMO, you shouldn't strive for `main` to be as small, or large, or anything else in particular as possible. Rather, `main` should be a function just about like any other. It should have accomplish something useful. Like any other function, it should have a clearly defined level of abstraction at which it operates, and (for the most part) it should try to stick to it.

As a natural consequence of being bigger, a bigger program will typically have more layers between `main` and the lowest levels of manipulation, so in a large program it'll typically have little code beyond creating objects and/or calling functions. I wouldn't consider that a particularly worthy goal in itself though. If it fits well with the size and type of program you're writing great--but there's not necessarily a good reason to force it if it doesn't happen to fit or work out well that way.

Comment: This does look cleaner.  I wasn't sure if such a small implementation would've benefited from a `Game` class, so I just kept it procedural.  Or would you say that pretty much any good game implementation should use classes?

Comment: @Jamal: I'm not sure whether any good game implementation should necessarily use classes. It seemed to work out here, but I haven't really thought it through for other cases.

Comment: I suppose I should get familiar with good design practices, then.  That's probably one of the things I can really improve on, considering my C++ practices seem decent.

Answer (score 4):

My personal preference is that main should try as hard as possible to do nothing but utilize other classes or functions; preprocessor, selection, and loop constructs notwithstanding.

Because of this policy (it's a little to simple to warrant the use of classes):

1. The readability is much better and the flow is easier to understand.
2. It encapsulates changes to the point that the ability to change the hard-coded word to instead use a file to get the word possibly from a list of words and only have to change one function.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


bool IsCorrectGuess(const char guess, std::string const& word);
void UpdateWrongGuesses(const char guess, std::string const& word, std::string& wrongGuesses);
void UpdateCorrectGuesses(const char guess, std::string const& word, std::string& correctGuesses);
void DisplayStatus(const unsigned int triesLeft, std::string const& guessedWord, std::string const& wrongGuesses);
void ObfuscateWord(const std::string &word, std::string& guessedWord);
void DisplayGameEnd(const std::string& guessedWord, const std::string& word);
char GetGuess();
void AppendAttemptedGuesses(std::string& attemptedGuesses, char guess);
bool IsGameOver(unsigned int triesLeft, const std::string& guessedWord, const std::string& word);
bool IsWordGuessed(const std::string& guessedWord, const std::string& word);
bool HasTriesRemaining(unsigned int triesLeft);
std::string GetWord();
void DecrementGuesses(unsigned int& triesLeft);
bool IsHyphen(int c);
void RunGame(const std::string& word);
void MainLoop(unsigned int guesses_remaining, std::string guessedWord, const std::string& word, std::string& attempted_guesses, std::string& wrongGuesses);

int main() {

    const std::string& word = GetWord();
    RunGame(word);

}

bool IsHyphen(int c) {
    return c == '-';
}

void ObfuscateWord(const std::string &word, std::string& guessedWord) {
    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i != word.size(); ++i) {
        guessedWord += (isspace(word[i])) ? ' ' : (IsHyphen(word[i]) ? '-' : '*');
    }
}

void DisplayStatus(const unsigned int triesLeft, std::string const& guessedWord, std::string const& wrongGuesses) {
    std::cout << "\n\nRemaining Tries: " << triesLeft;
    std::cout << "\nWrong Guesses  : " << wrongGuesses;
    std::cout << "\n\n" << guessedWord << "\n\n";
}

void UpdateCorrectGuesses(const char guess, std::string const& word, std::string& correctGuesses) {
    for (std::string::size_type i = 0; i < word.size(); ++i) {
        if (word[i] == guess) {
            correctGuesses[i] = guess;
        }
    }
}

void UpdateWrongGuesses(const char guess, std::string const& word, std::string& wrongGuesses) {
    wrongGuesses += guess;
}

bool IsCorrectGuess(const char guess, std::string const& word) {
    return (word.find(guess) != std::string::npos);
}

void DisplayGameEnd(const std::string& guessedWord, const std::string& word) {
    if (IsWordGuessed(guessedWord, word)) {
        std::cout << "\n\nYou've guessed the word/phrase!\n\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "\n\nYou've been hanged...\n\n";
        std::cout << "The word/phrase is: " << word;
    }
}

char GetGuess() {
    std::cout << "\nGuess a letter: ";
    char guess;
    std::cin >> guess;
    guess = tolower(guess);
    return guess;
}

void AppendAttemptedGuesses(std::string& attemptedGuesses, char guess) {
    attemptedGuesses += guess;
}

bool IsGameOver(unsigned int triesLeft, const std::string& guessedWord, const std::string& word) {
    return (!HasTriesRemaining(triesLeft) || IsWordGuessed(guessedWord, word));
}

bool IsWordGuessed(const std::string& guessedWord, const std::string& word) {
    return guessedWord == word;
}

bool HasTriesRemaining(unsigned int triesLeft) {
    return triesLeft > 0;
}

std::string GetWord() {
    return "rabbit rabbit";
}

void DecrementGuesses(unsigned int& triesLeft) {
    --triesLeft;
}

void RunGame(const std::string& word) {
    std::string guessedWord;
    ObfuscateWord(word, guessedWord);

    unsigned int guesses_remaining = 8;
    std::string wrongGuesses;
    DisplayStatus(guesses_remaining, guessedWord, wrongGuesses);

    std::string attempted_guesses;
    MainLoop(guesses_remaining, guessedWord, word, attempted_guesses, wrongGuesses);

    DisplayGameEnd(guessedWord, word);
}

void MainLoop(unsigned int guesses_remaining, std::string guessedWord, const std::string& word, std::string& attempted_guesses, std::string& wrongGuesses) {
    while (!IsGameOver(guesses_remaining, guessedWord, word)) {
        char current_guess = GetGuess();
        AppendAttemptedGuesses(attempted_guesses, current_guess);
        if (IsCorrectGuess(current_guess, word)) {
            UpdateCorrectGuesses(current_guess, word, guessedWord);
        } else {
            UpdateWrongGuesses(current_guess, word, wrongGuesses);
            DecrementGuesses(guesses_remaining);
        }
        DisplayStatus(guesses_remaining, guessedWord, wrongGuesses);
    }
}
```

Comment: I could try something like that (after first eliminating all the prototypes).  I understand that `main()` should do little, but I'm not always aware on where to draw the line.

Comment: @Jamal What's wrong with function declarations?

Comment: Nothing in general, but it could look cluttering if there a lot of functions.  They will also have to be maintained along with the function definitions if I change the name and/or arguments.

Comment: @Jamal That's where code refactoring plug-ins come in handy such as Visual Assist X. Which is exactly what I did to refactor your code, basically highlighted sections and called "Extract Method" :)